# iPhone - daylightSavingTimeOffset crash (???)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have these two lines inside a block that is called when the app is about to quit

```
NSTimeZone* systemTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSTimeInterval delta = [systemTimeZone daylightSavingTimeOffset];
```

I have these lines there for weeks. They were working perfectly. Now, the app crashes on the second line showing this error:

> -[NSCFString daylightSavingTimeOffset]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x1534b0
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString
>   daylightSavingTimeOffset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1534b0'**

what? any clues? thanks.

Comment: Are those lines actually running one after another like you have in your example?

Comment: I was asking because it is strange to for a call to a method that returns one type is already returned as another type (NSString instead of NSTimeZone). I did some digging around and found a possible cause which I posted below. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If those lines are being called in order and you are getting that message it looks you are over releasing the systemTimeZone somewhere. It just so happens that a valid `NSString*` is occupying the memory where the cached systemTimeZone was stored.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Special Considerations**
>   If you get the system time zone, it is
>   cached by the application and does not change if the user subsequently
>   changes the system time zone. The next time you invoke systemTimeZone,
>   you get back the same time zone you originally got. You have to invoke
>   resetSystemTimeZone to clear the cached object.

So consider this

```
NSTimeZone *systemTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSLog(@"%lf", [systemTimeZone daylightSavingTimeOffset]); //This works
[systemTimeZone release]; //Testing release do not actually do this

systemTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSLog(@"%lf", [systemTimeZone daylightSavingTimeOffset]); //This works
[systemTimeZone release]; //Testing release do not actually do this

systemTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSLog(@"%lf", [systemTimeZone daylightSavingTimeOffset]); //This crashes EXC_BAD_ACCESS
//The cached systemTimeZone at this point has been over released.
```

Where I get my `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` it would also be possible for an NSString* to reside there as I mentioned earlier and that would result in exception being raised. So just make sure you are not improperly releasing it anywhere.

Comment: The problem solved alone, but before that I confirmed that the variable was being released for some unknown reason. I have no release line for that variable but it is autorelease anyway. So, I suppose you were right and I am accepting the answer. thanks.

Comment: a call to [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]; from anywhere in your app will give you a reference to a same cached NSTimeZone object. If you call [NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone], that cached object gets cleared (autoreleased I think) and subsequent calls to [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] would result in a new object.   Now, if we have references to the previous object, that would be a problem.

Comment: Pre-ARC that could of been more common. Only way for that to happen now is to store the object using an `unsafe_unretained` pointer.